# How to create multiple app based on the Activity Class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

MainActivity as my main app as Start the app, but the SecondActivity, ThirdActivity, FourthActivity will appear only in Home Screen, but not in App List Screen. Is that able to do it? Just like a one app with four Icon generated.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MultipleApps"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/source_01"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ThirdActivity"
        android:label="@string/source_02"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FourthActivity"
        android:label="@string/source_03"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlT5P.jpg)

Comment: If the others `activity` is just normal activity you only need to make 4 icon in MainActivity then start activity when user click on 1 icon

Comment: @KiluSs i means to have other activity place in device Home Screen. Each activity have owe icon and label

Comment: have you try app widget?

Comment: @KiluSs, thanks for your advice. However widget need to drag it out by user itself. I was hope that i able to appear once the app is installed

Comment: I'm afraid that can't be done. But you can create several apps and go to others by `intent`. Or if you only can make one just add a guide for user on startup screen to set the widget themselves.